# Tensorflow C++ API assign variable value

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am using the tensorflow c++ api and would like to assign a value to a variable. However, whenever running this code I see that the variable itself is never being mutated. The documentation says that this should be possible:

> Assign: Update 'ref' by assigning 'value' to it.

Here is some simplified code:

```
Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();

auto var = Variable(root, {1}, DT_DOUBLE);
auto assigned = Assign(root, var, Const(root, {1.0}));

ClientSession session(root);

session.Run({}, {assigned}, &out); // out[0] returns 1.0
session.Run({}, {var}, &out); // gives: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem.

The simple solution was this:

```
Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();

auto var = Variable(root, {1}, DT_DOUBLE);
auto assigned = Assign(root, var, Const(root, {1.0}));

ClientSession session(root);

// initialize first
session.Run({}, {}, {Operation(assigned.node())}, &out);
// now run
session.Run({}, {var}, &out);
```

Comment: This code works well with data types double and int32 but when using int64 it is giving segmentation fault. Any idea about it ??